# How to take 2 columns to generate sequence of length N and add as columns in R?

Tags: r, data.table, sequence

I have a data frame with 2 columns min and max. I wanted to generate sequence b/w these numbers for each row.

```
df <- data.table("ID"=c("A","B","C"),
                 "mn" = c(1,2,3),
                 "mx" = c(10,5,10)
                 )
> df
    ID mn mx
 1:  A  1  10
 2:  B  2  5
 3:  C  3  10
```

I want to take these 2 columns and generate 4 sequence numbers for each row

```
>df
 ID | mn | mx | S1 | s2    | S3 |  s4
  A    1   10    1     4     7      10
  B    2   5     2     3     4      5
  C    3   10    3     5.33  7.66   10
```

I can iterate over rows and use seq(mn, mx, length=N) but I want to apply this operation on 1 Million rows , please suggest efficient solution .

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: The easiest way is `S1=mn,S2=mn+1,S3=mn+2,S4=mx` if the sequence is exactly as you described.

Comment: I can iterate over each row and use seq(mn, mx, length=4) but is there any other efficient solution

Comment: @FrankZhang what if the number of sequences required is 7 ?

Comment: You can modify any of the answers below to use `seq(mn, mx, length.out = 4)` instead of `mn:mx` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `apply` :

```
cbind(df, t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[1]:x[2])))

#   mn mx V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:  1  4  1  2  3  4
#2:  2  5  2  3  4  5
#3:  3  6  3  4  5  6
```

Or `mapply` :

```
cbind(df, t(mapply(`:`, df$mn, df$mx)))
```

Comment: Well... today I learned about the matrix transpose function [t](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/t).

Answer (score 2):

Another vectorized option using `data.table` which should be faster without going through row by row:

```
df[, paste0("s", 1L:4L) := {
        d <- (mx - mn) / 3
        .(mn, mn + d, mn + 2*d, mx)
    }]
```

---

To generalize, thelatemail has suggested:

```
N <- 4L
df[, paste0("s", seq(N)) := transpose(Map(`+`, mn, 
    lapply((mx - mn) / (N-1), `*`, seq(0, N-1))
))]
```

Or equivalently but longer winded but I think it will be faster:

```
N <- 4L #assuming N >= 2
d <- df[, (mx - mn) / (N - 1)]
init <- df[["mn"]]
for (n in 1L:N) {
    set(df, j=paste0("s", n), value=init + (n-1) * d)
}
```

Comment: Nice - i've made an ugly attempt to generalise this logic: `n <- 4; df[, paste0("s", seq(n)) := transpose(Map(\`+\`, mn, lapply((mx - mn) / (n-1), \`*\`, seq(0,n-1))))]`

Comment: @thelatemail sorry just saw your post below. would you like to add your code to it and i remove from mine?

Comment: Nah, all good - your answer/logic is much better as it doesn't loop over every row. Much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(cols = list(mn:mx)) %>%
 unnest_wider(cols) %>%
 rename_at(vars(-mn, -mx), ~ paste0("s", 1:length(.)))

     mn    mx    s1    s2    s3    s4
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     1     2     3     4
2     2     5     2     3     4     5
3     3     6     3     4     5     6
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cols = Map(`:`, mn, mx)) %>%
 unnest_wider(cols) %>%
 rename_at(vars(-mn, -mx), ~ paste0("s", 1:length(.)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In *data.table*, loop over `mn` and `mx` with `Map` and then `transpose` and assign `:=`:

```
df[, paste0("s", seq(4)) := transpose(Map(seq, mn, mx, length.out=4))]
df
#   ID mn mx s1       s2       s3 s4
#1:  A  1 10  1 4.000000 7.000000 10
#2:  B  2  5  2 3.000000 4.000000  5
#3:  C  3 10  3 5.333333 7.666667 10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     mutate(cols = map2(mn, mx, `:`)) %>%
     unnest_wider(cols)
```